# Error Link 2019

Tags: c++

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl show(struct stringy const &)" (?show@@YAXABUstringy@@@Z) referenced in function _main   F:\c++代码\exercise8.42\exercise8.42\Source.obj   exercise8.42

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

struct stringy{
    char * str;
    int ct;
};

void set(stringy & r1, char * a);
void show(const stringy & r1);
;

int main()
{
    stringy beany;
    char testing[] = "Reality isn't, and show() go there";
    set(beany, testing);
    show(beany);

    return 0;
}

void set(stringy & r1, char *a)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (a[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    r1.str = new char;
    r1.ct = i;
    for (int b = 0; b < i; b++)
        r1.str[b] = a[b];
    r1.str[i + 1] = '\0';
}

void show(stringy & r1)
{
    std::cout << *r1.str;
}
```

I am just beginning code in c++.

Comment: Double check the signature of the declaration and the definition. `void show(const stringy & r1)`

Comment: `void show(stringy & r1)` is not the same as `void show(const stringy & r1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @drescherjm It is a simple typo.  The function definition does not match the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`const` of the function argument is part of that function's signature. Thus

```
void show(const stringy & r1);
```

is not the same as

```
void show(stringy & r1);
```

At the compilation of `main ()` the compiler is aware only of `void show(const stringy & r1);` but then the linker doesn't find its implementation since you implemented

```
void show(stringy & r1);
```

and not

```
void show(const stringy & r1);
```

The solution is just to add `const` before `stringy & r1` at the implementation of `show`.